# UML Use Case Diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

I am wondering if my Use case diagram is correct.

I wonder what should i write in the relationship.Should I go through using `<<include>>` or to use `<<extend>>`.

Could someone tell me if I am in a right way.Can you Explain what is the difference between `<<include>>` and `<<extend>>`

This is my diagram :

[image]

Thank You.~

Comment: If an answer is helpful for you, please upvote it and / or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions that address to this problem. I have found the answer of Doug Knesek useful:
Extend is used when a use case conditionally adds steps to another first class use case.

For example, imagine "Withdraw Cash" is a use case of an ATM machine. "Assess Fee" would extend Withdraw Cash and describe the conditional "extension point" that is instantiated when the ATM user doesn't bank at the ATM's owning institution. Notice that the basic "Withdraw Cash" use case stands on its own, without the extension.

Include is used to extract use case fragments that are duplicated in multiple use cases. The included use case cannot stand alone and the original use case is not complete without the included one. This should be used sparingly an only in cases where the duplication is significant and exists by design (rather than by coincidence).

For example, the flow of events that occurs at the beginning of every ATM use case (when the user puts in their ATM card, enters their PIN, and is shown the main menu) would be a good candidate for an include.

Click this link for more answers:
[What's is the difference between include and extend in use case diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696927/whats-is-the-difference-between-include-and-)  extend-in-use-case-diagram

Comment: It depends upon your system flow. The only thing to remember is, <<include>> is necessary  while <<extends>> is optional or simply extends the behavior of a base use case.

Comment: about the arrow points in <<include>> and <<extend>> could you explain more.?

Answer (score 0):

You find a lot of questions on SO about how to distinguish `include` and `extend`.
See here:
[extends vs include in usecase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313623/extends-vs-include-in-usecase)