# Need to confirm whether this use case diagram is correct

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

[image: Diagram]

What the digram shows is a user:

1. Submits an inquiry into the system.
2. The user can amend their enquiry
3. If the user finds a counter-party, they can then negotiate which results in a trade execution.
4. This then results in a private auction between the two counter-parties.
5. The private negotiation then extends to a public auction.

The problem I am having is understanding the difference between includes and extends. 
Can someone please clarify which use cases include or extend to the other use case?

Answer (score 2):

You find a lot of questions on SO about how to distinguish `include` and `extend`.
See here:
[extends vs include in usecase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313623/extends-vs-include-in-usecase)

Please note that you should use verbs instead of nouns as use case names.
Also, you have drawn a generalization between actor and use case. This is semantically wrong, it should be a plain line, not an arrow.